# Java Exception error i/o

Tags: java, exception, ioexception, runtimeexception

I am getting an error when I try to read my file abc.txt in my D drive.
Even I tried format : "D:\EDU\java\abc.txt"

Here's my code :

```
package javapro;

import java.io.FileInputStream;

public class office {

    public static void main (String[] args)throws Exception {
        FileInputStream apple = new FileInputStream ("D:/EDU/java/abc.txt");
        int din;
        while ((din=apple.read())!=-1){
            System.out.println((char)din);
        }
        apple.close();
    }
}
```

My Error :

```
Exception in thread "main" java.io.FileNotFoundException: D:\EDU\java\abc.txt (The system cannot find the file specified)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.open0(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.open(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at javapro.office.main(office.java:8)
```

Comment: Did you put the abc.txt in the right place (D:\EDU\java\)? Also, if you use backslash, it should be "D:\\EDU\\java\\abc.txt".

Answer (score 1):

Make sure the file is actually located in that directory. Right-click and click on Properties to check the path.

If you've done that, change all the `\` to `/` or `\\`.

Answer (score 1):

The error is self-explanatory. The file isn't where you have told the application it is. Check your path to make sure that it leads to the file.

Answer (score 0):

1) Change the code as below

```
 FileInputStream apple = new FileInputStream ("D:\\EDU\\java\\abc.txt");
```

or

```
 InputStream is = getClass().getResourceAsStream("abc.txt");

//if abc.txt is present in classpath
```

From InputStream, you have to read the data.

**EDIT**: Resolve non static error

```
InputStream is = office.class.getClass().getResourceAsStream("abc.txt");
```

Comment: package javapro;

import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.InputStream;

public class office {

 public static void main (String[] args)throws Exception {
  InputStream is = getClass().getResourceAsStream("abc.txt");
int din;
FileInputStream apple;
while ((din=apple.read())!=-1){
System.out.println((char)din);
 }
apple.close();
}
 
}

Comment: error:  Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: 
 Cannot make a static reference to the non-static method getClass() from the type Object

 at javapro.office.main(office.java:9)

Comment: Try the first one with \\.  Or Add your code in constructor of the class and create object in main method.